# facebook messenger with ibm watson emoji input

Tags: node.js, facebook, chatbot, watson

I now currently doing facebook integration using IBM Watson. In facebook, documention didn't provide anything about emoji. How emoji going works when Watson conversation receive emoji from facebook messenger?

Answer (score 0):

Watson conversation will do nothing with emojis. If you have them in your training data, it may use it in the learning, but more as "keywords" then actual meaning.

Watson Tone analyser should understand emojis though, at least from a tone perspective.

Comment: means there is no way for IBM watson to recongise the emoji from facebook messenger chatbot? im using node.js backend

Comment: Why does it need to recognize?